# Decimal.TryParse Fails to parse integer value

Tags: c#, parsing, decimal

What am I missing:

```
decVal = Decimal.Parse(myAr[0]);
```

Or

```
Decimal.TryParse(myAr[0], out decVal);
```

Fails !

Input string was not in correct foramt.

```
myAr[0] is "678016".
```

Tried to add `NumberStyle.Any` and `CultureInfo.InvarialtCulture` but got the same results.

More info on the string:

it is concatenated with some letters in hebrew and a "\u200e" space between them. and then I use split(' ') to get the numbers back.

This is probably the source of this error, but when I check the myAr[0] in the watch it is pure string....

Comment: Please provide a reproduction. This should work.

Comment: Whitespaces? Does `Decimal.TryParse(myAr[0].Trim(), out decVal);` work?

Comment: Check the actual value of `myAr[0]`. I can't reproduce.

Comment: `Decimal.Parse("678016");` works on my machine...

Comment: possibly `myArr[0]` is an empty string. and you have value `678016` at some other index of array. please print the array and double check it.

Comment: Of course, put a breakpoint on the `Parse` line and you'll see _precisely_ what is happening.

Comment: Sorry to get 4 downvotes on a real problem. Still working to resolve this though.I can upload images of the debugger. it happens.

Comment: That might be because `Decimal.Parse("678016")` is tried and true and *will* work. So the much more likely explanation is, that the error is somewhere else. Most likely of all that `myAr[0]` simply *isn't* `"678016"` my guess is still, that it might be `"678016 "` or something like that. The only way to be sure is to set a breakpoint on the parse line and look at what `myAr[0]` is at that precise moment. Maybe even use a temporary variable before it and use that. `var temp = myAr[0]; Decimal.TryParse(temp, out decVal);`

Comment: Maybe you can show us the original string and how you split it to get `myAr`?

Comment: @Corak - thanks, I've found it and posted it. the string has some special chars inside and the watch didn't show them. took me a while to figure it out....

Comment: Never trust the watch! ^_^ Especially whitespaces or "invisible" characters are very hard to detect that way. And I just remembered: `Debug.Assert(myAr[0] == "678016")`...

Comment: Well, in good old C++ days I could have checked the memory, I wonder if it can be done in c# b/c I would have figured it immediately....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guys I've found the answer, I'll rewrite the question for future generation.
The Original string was a concatenation of letters and numbers separated with a special sequence to preserve the order in a rtl situation: "\u200E".

The number where extracted later using string.split(' ') which seems to work OK (in the watch) be it caused the problem.

once I used string.split("\u200e").ToCharArray() I got the same results, but now the decimal.Parse is working.
It looks like the special char was still inside the string, invisible to the watch.

Answer (score 2):

This is weird, on my machine (.NET 4) even this works:

```
Decimal.TryParse("asdf123&*", out someDecimal);
```

By works I mean that `TryParse` returns false, **no** exception is thrown.

`Parse` method may throw an exception - maybe you have some whitespace or string literally contains " (quotes)?

Comment: And this is an answer...how?

Comment: Actually a very good point! `TryParse` should never throw an exception!

Comment: OP didn't specify which type of Parse threw the exception, however.  _Should_ have been more specific, but wasn't.

Comment: The exception was on the Parse, tryParse just returns false... tried them both to figure out what is wrong...